# and - or query with gtrendsR how to do

Tags: r, gtrendsr

I Tried gtrendsR and I found it very usefull. but I don't know how to do an and/or query. 
For example with this syntax:

```
library(gtrendsR)
library("ggthemes")
gconnect(usr = "myaddress", psw = "mypassword", verbose = TRUE)
dp2 <- gtrends(c("Petronas", "Castrol", "Fuchs"), geo = c("IT") , start_date = "2013-06-17", end_date = "2016-03-17")
plot(dp2) + ggplot2::ggtitle("Castrol vs Fuchs vs Petronas in Italy") +
scale_colour_solarized("blue") +
theme_fivethirtyeight() +  geom_line(size = 1)
```

...How can I search Petronas and/or Selenia (they are the same brand of lubricant) but not "Petronas Towers" (not pertinent)? In Google trends I would write "Petronas"+"Selenia"-"Petronas Towers". Is it possible also in gtrendsR?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was quite easy:[Here](https://github.com/PMassicotte/gtrendsR/issues/86)  the solution

```
gtrends('"Petronas"+"Selenia"-"Petronas Towers"')$trend
```